# Xamarin: Any difference between using Java.IO and System.IO

Tags: android, xamarin, io, java-io, system.io.file

I am wondering if there is any difference between using Java.IO and System.IO as both can achieve the same stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is difference between `Java.IO` and `System.IO`. `System.IO` is a namespace that comes from .NET BCL.

> The System.IO namespace contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support.

Whereas `Java.IO` is a package that is available as a part of JDK.

> Java.io package provides classes for system input and output through data streams, serialization and the file system.

Since System.Io is a part of BCL we can use most of the classes in that for IO operations across platforms

> Each platform has a slightly different directory structure, and different filesystem capabilities - for example Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android support most System.IOfunctionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.iO on both android and iOS, but you can only use Java.IO on the android side. So technically you could set up a shared project that will be referenced by both your iOS and Android projects and share the IO logic there. With the only difference being that paths to the resources will be different on iOS vs Android.